# jQuery: Grab textContent From Child Element

Tags: jquery, ajax

HTML

```
<a href="report.php?id=5&file=name.jpg" id="5" class="report">Report Content<span class="hidden">name.jpg</span></a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.report').click(function(event) {
    var id = this.id;
    var file = $(this).children('span').textContent;

    alert(file);

    $(this).fadeOut("slow");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'id=' + id + '&file=' + file,
        url: 'http://www.sitename.com/report.php',
        success: function() {

        }
    });
    return false;   
}
```

The line of code I'm having trouble with:

```
    var file = $(this).children('span').textContent;
```

How can I properly grab that span's text content and store it in a variable `file` ?

Also, is there a better way I should be doing this, or is my method okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
var file = $(this).children('span').text();
```

Since `children` returns an instance of jQuery, it won't have a `textContent` property. Alternatively, if you do want to use the native `textContent` property, you can access the underlying DOM element:

```
var file = $(this).children('span')[0].textContent;
```

However, be aware that that is slightly different from the jQuery version in that the `text` method returns the concatenated text from all selected nodes (in your current code, that is just the single `span`, but if you added another `span` element, it would be different).